# Generate distinct entires for a string (dots to be used)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have the following string:

```
char *str = "test";
```

I need to generate distinct entries from it using dots, e.g. the following would be generated:

```
test
t.est
te.st
tes.t
t.e.s.t
t.e.st
te.s.t
...
```

Note: cannot have a dot at the start nor at the end.

What I have currently is able to generate some of them, but not all, I tried multiple things, such as:
1. On the bit level (dot on and off for each iteration) which sounded like the most reasonable to date, but I had an obstacle.
2. Just a nested loop which would generate based on equality, e.g. (x, y, and compare x, y with i (where i would serve as the loop for generating the new string).

Current code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[] = "test";

    for (int k = 0; k < sizeof(str) - 1; ++k) {
        for (int x = k; x < sizeof(str) - 1; ++x) {
            for (int y = x + 1; y < sizeof(str) - 1; ++y) {
                char tmp[512], *p = tmp;
                for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(str); ++i) {
                    *p++ = str[i];
                    if (i == x || i == y)
                        *p++ = '.';
                }
                *p++ = '\0';
                printf("%s\n", tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives:

```
t.e.st
t.es.t
t.est.
te.s.t
te.st.
tes.t.
te.s.t
te.st.
tes.t.
tes.t.
```

Is it best to use the bit-level thing and if so, any suggestions to it?  Or is it better if I continue on the current and fix it up to work correctly (please provide solutions)?

Note, that performance isn't really needed here, this is just a one time thing (on startup) so, anything will do as long as it works.

Comment: Are you unsure if this is C or C++?

Comment: @Jongware No, I tagged it C and C++ on purpose, language shouldn't really matter, solution is what matters.  but C/C++ is more preferable I guess...

Comment: Does a pure C++ solution (one that won't compile in C) count?  If not, then you shouldn't include a C++ tag.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I provided that I don't care what language it is.  As long as it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word has four letters, so there are three breaks where you could insert a dot `'.'`. There will be 2<sup>n-1</sup> combinations of inserting/not inserting dots. You can encode them as binary numbers:

```
dec bin word
--- --- -------
  0 000 test
  1 001 t.est
  2 010 te.st
  3 011 t.e.st
  4 100 tes.t
  5 101 t.es.t
  6 110 te.s.t
  7 111 t.e.s.t
```

What you need to do now is to make a "mask" that changes from 0 to 2<sup>n-1</sup>-1, inclusive, and interpret this mask as a sequence of dots in a nested loop, like this:

```
string s = "test";
for (int mask = 0 ; mask != 1 << (s.size()-1) ; mask++) {
    cout << s[0];
    for (int i = 0 ; i != s.size()-1 ; i++) {
        if (mask & (1<<i)) {
            cout << ".";
        }
        cout << s[i+1];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/edCKRp)

Comment: I like how I doubted myself 500 times before actually doing this, and this is why I provided a first point with the bit solution and didn't continue on it due to the slack of self-confidence.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use an integer as a bitmask: for each bit, print a `.` if it is set.  If you iterate all values from `0` to `2 ** (len-1)` you will enumerate all possible positions for the dot with all possible combinations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "test";
    int len = strlen(str);

    for (int bits = 0; bits < (1 << (len - 1)); bits++) {
         putchar(str[0]);
         for (int j = 1; j < len; j++) {
             if (bits & (1 << (j - 1)))
                 putchar('.');
             putchar(str[j]);
         }
         putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This function should do what you expect:

```
void dotify(char *str) {
    int nr = 1 << (strlen(str)-1);
    char buf[strlen(str)*2];

    while (nr--) {
        int i;
        char *ptr = buf;
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
            *ptr++ = str[i];
            if (nr & (1 << i))
                *ptr++ = '.';
        }
        *ptr = '\0';
        puts(buf);
    }
}
```

The fundamental idea behind this solution is to map each dot-place to a digit of a binary number with strlen(str)-1 digits. Count this number from 0-n. Digit 0 means "don't set dot", while 1 means "set dot"